# workbook is a class or object in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new learner in vba. I am so confused in classes and object. e.g. workbook is a class or object. Some one says that workbook is a class and someone says that workbook is a object. If workbook is a object then object browser which is in vba shows that workbook is a class.

If I write- Dim wb as Workbook 
So here wb is what?
Workbook is what?

Please resolve my issue and thanks for advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/

Answer (score 1):

It's both. A Class is a template, or definition, of an object; an object is an instance of a class.

Your 'wb' is - or will be - an object. After the code `Dim wb as Workbook` it is not anything, as nothing has been assigned to it, but it has been set up so that any object assigned to it must be a instance of class Workbook. If you followed up you first line with something like `wb = Workbooks(1)` then wb would now represent a Workbook object. If, on the other hand, you tried something like `wb = "I am a string"` you'd get an error as the Dim said that it can only be a workbook.

Comment: And in VBA, since you are working with objects, you need to use the `Set` keyword.  e.g `Set wb = ThisWorkbook`